# Function not evaluating in GHCI

Tags: haskell, ghci

If I assign a var to maxBound :

```
let bInt = maxBound
```

evaluation of `bInt` prints ()

but if I type bInt

```
bInt :: Int
prints : 9223372036854775807
```

Why does bInt not evaluate until I type

```
bInt (bInt :: Int) ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`maxBound` is a function in the [`Bounded`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Bounded) type class. By default, GHCi appears to choose the instance for `()`, which returns `()`. You can force it to use another instance by adding a type signature.

```
let bInt :: Int; bInt = maxBound
bInt -- 9223372036854775807

let x = maxBound
x :: () -- ()
x :: Bool -- True
x :: Char -- '\1114111'
```